# Handle concurrent requests using async ExpressJS route handler

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, async-await

I need to do a long running task in an express route handler.

```
export const handler: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  logger.info("reached inside handler", { data: { time: new Date().toISOString() } });

  let results;
  if(someConditions){
    results = await timeConsumingFunction(...);
  } else{
    results = await fastFunction(...);
  }

  return res.status(200).json({ results });
};
```

My assumption was that the route handler will release the resource as soon as it reaches to `await` line, but based on my observation, it doesn't release the resource immediately.

When the first client calls the route, it prints the line `reached inside handler` and waits at `await timeConsumingFunction` line.
However when the second client calls the route, I expect to see the `reached inside handler` immediately, but this is not happening. I can only see the log message either after first call is completed or after some random time (from a few seconds up to one minute delay).

My question is how to allow multiple clients to connect to the route (and reach to the route handler) while some existing client(s) is waiting there already. Or at least to know the exact procedure on how ExpressJS/NodeJS release the resource when it reaches to a `await`.

Comment: Just to be clear, `timeConsumingFunciton` is not a CPU intensive task, I used a simple sleep for `timeConsumingFunction` in my tests:
`new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 250000))`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that that the issue is not the server side with the help some colleagues.

I used Google Chrome as a client and it turned out that it was the client (browser) that sends the request with delay when another tab was waiting. I didn't experience this behaviour with `curl` or `postman`